# Date format in richTextBox, when passing date values from dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, richtextbox

A simple SQL query is performed and the dataGridView1 on my form does show the values from the date and name columns of my database, as expected . The dates in the dataGridView1 appear in the desired format ("MM/dd/yyyy").

Next,  the contents of the dataGridView1 are passed on to richTextBox1. The date values here (in the richTextBox1) do appear in the desired format ("MM/dd/yyyy"), however they also include a time value of 12:00:00 AM  in all cases (eg 2/6/2020 12:00:00 AM).

I want to get rid of this time component of the date values in the richTextBox1. I understand I must declare somehow the desired format for the values of the column date (first column of dataGridView1) in the richTextBox1, but have not managed to do it, so far. Any suggestions?

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = SelectData();

            richTextBox1.Text = "REPORT \n\n";

            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "-";

                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\t" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t";
                }
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n";
            }
        }
        
        private DataTable SelectData()
        {
            DataTable dtSelectData = new DataTable();

            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT date, name FROM person", con))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        dtSelectData.Load(reader);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Database Message:\n" + ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            return dtSelectData;
        }
```

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value` is your DateTime values in `dataGridView1`?

Comment: The first cell in each row is the DateTime value, so I assume it's the dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format date from `dataGridView1` cell, you can cast cell's value (`object`) to `DateTime` type and use `ToString("Some DateTime Format")` on it after.

Safe and simple way to cast is to combine check, that cell value is of `DateTime` type and cast it to `DateTime` type if it is. It could be done with `is` operator:

```
if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value is DateTime dt) { ... }
```

It calls **Pattern matching**, you can read about it on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching).
So if condition will be `true` (which means cell value is of `DateTime` type) - you can use `dt` variable value with `ToString("SomeFormat")` over it to format value as you want:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    object cellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;

    if (cellValue is DateTime dt)
        richTextBox1.Text += "\t" + dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "\t";
    else
        richTextBox1.Text += "\t" + cellValue?.ToString() + "\t";
}
```

At test this way looks fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()
```

with

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

to prevent time.

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value` is `object` type and its `ToString()` method has ho overload to accept `"MM/dd/yyyy"` format as argument.